# c# type of T of method called from extension method

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I've written a small library that generates SQL statements from POCO objects in c# (https://github.com/developer82/Poco.Sql).

I have an extension method that returns an instance of [QueryBuilder](https://github.com/developer82/Poco.Sql/blob/master/poco.sql/QueryBuilder.cs). And QueryBuilder has it's own methods that construct the SQL statement - one of them is Where - so I could do something like this:

```
var sql = myUserObject.PocoSql().Select().Where<User>(u => u.UserId = 5);
```

What I'm asking is do I really need to pass the type T to the where method since I already know what object I'm working with. Basically, I would image this as the way to write:

```
var sql = myUserObject.PocoSql().Select().Where(u => u.UserId = 5);
```

I might be totally off base here but figured it's worth asking

Comment: If compiler understands what the type is you don't need to provide the type. Try removing the type and if it is required you'll get an error during compile time

Comment: @dotnetom do I need to make any changes to the where method?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you should make the `QueryBuilder` class generic:

```
public class QueryBuilder<T>
{
    private T _obj;
    public QueryBuilder(T obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now when you start chaining the methods in your fluent interface the context of the original object type will be preserved and you no longer need to explicitly specify the object type on each method.

Also don't forget to update your `PocoSql` extension method as well which is where your fluent interface starts:

```
public static class PocoSqlExtensions
{
    public static QueryBuilder<T> PocoSql<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return new QueryBuilder<T>(obj);
    }
}
```

Basically if you want strong typing and the compiler being able to infer the object types at compile time, forget about the `System.Object` type.

Answer (score 0):

Your QueryBuilder Class must be generic. So you will Precise the T Type only on your Instance.